# How can I set value of layout_weight of a radio button in Anko DSL (Android)?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, anko

I'm using Anko DSL for creating UI instead of XML. But when I'm going to set layout_weight parameter of a radio button in Anko way I'm getting error.

I've tried following way:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    verticalLayout() {
        radioGroup() {
            orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
            radioButton {
                id = RADIO_SECOND
                text = "second(s)"

            }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = wrapContent, weight = 0.25F)

            // Few more radio button
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives error `Error:(107, 19) 'inline fun <T : View> RadioButton.lparams(width: Int = ..., height: Int = ..., weight: Float): RadioButton' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary`.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Whats the context you use this in? So essentially what code is surrounding your snippet?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I've update the post with surrounding codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By specifying the `weight` parameter of the `radioButton`, you're choosing to use the [`lparams`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/anko/library/generated/sdk25/src/Layouts.kt#L960) function defined on the `_LinearLayout` class of Anko, so you're basically trying to give the `radioButton` a weight in the context of the `verticalLayout` you have wrapping your entire layout.

To give it weight in the context of the `radioGroup`, you can use another [`lparams`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/anko/library/generated/sdk25/src/Layouts.kt#L1080) function, whose similar parameter is named `initWeight`:

```
verticalLayout {
    radioGroup {
        orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
        radioButton {
            id = RADIO_SECOND
            text = "second(s)"
        }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = wrapContent, initWeight = 0.25F)
    }
}
```

This will place the call into the right context.